# How to get the absolute path of a jar file in classpath given ONLY the jar file name?

Tags: java, jar, path, classpath

I am aware of getting the path of the jar that contains a specific class

```
<ClassName>.class.getProtectionDomain().getCodeSource().getLocation()
```

This is well explored in other SO questions.

---

My question is :

> "How to get the path of the JAR file **in the classpath** given **ONLY** the *JAR FILE NAME*.

Comment: To be clear, you are looking for a jar, that is in the classpath, which you have the name of, but you need the absolute path to?

Answer (score -1):

If you are looking to find the path to the currently running jar, try this

```
new File("", jarName);
```

If you are looking for something else in the classpath, you could use the same strategy, assuming that they are in the same directory as the jar.

However, if you have set the classpath, either by command line or in the manifest, it might be a little bit more complicated.

This is an example that I found on some website:

```
ClassLoader cl = ClassLoader.getSystemClassLoader();

URL[] urls = ((URLClassLoader)cl).getURLs();
```

This will get a list of absolute URLs that point to everything that has been loaded. All that you have to do is do `url.getFile()`